# Error: Could not find or load main class set

Tags: java, maven

I  got new laptop(Windows 7) and I am trying to set maven.

I have java home set

```
>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
```

Also I have Maven home set

```
>echo %M2_HOME%
C:\maven\apache-maven-3.2.1
```

Also in PATH I have set %JAVA_HOME%/bin and %M2_HOME%/bin set and I can see both path properly

```
>echo %PATH%

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;.....C:\maven\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;
```

But when I enter command "mvn" I am getting bellow error

```
>mvn

Error: Could not find or load main class set
```

So can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Java 7 is end of life. Try upgrading it. And your Maven is out of date too

Comment: @cricket_007 well, still running on Java 6 most of the applications at the office, so I would not be worried about Java 7 ;-)

Comment: @AxelH I hope your IT staff loves having known Java security problems

Answer (score 0):

The version of Maven you are using requires Java 6, from official doc:

https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html

Comment: I have my old laptop where i am running exact same version, but not working same on new laptop

`>mvn -version`
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14
Maven home: C:\maven\apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: In mvn.bat you can add this line at line 161 
`echo "%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %MAVEN_OPTS% -classpath %CLASSWORLDS_JAR% "-Dclassworlds.conf=%M2_HOME%\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=%M2_HOME%" %CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER% %MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS%"`

so you can see exactly what java command it is trying to execute to start maven. including classpath, class it tries to start, etc.

Comment: I could get similar error by removing some of the maven libs.your maven installation is probably corrupted, try to re-install properly maven . use this link: https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.1-bin.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the version of `maven`, should use `mvn -v` instead of `mvn` command alone. Remember to restart (close and then re-open) the Windows Command Line after setting the `PATH`

Comment: Yes I tried this as well, I am getting same result
`>mvn -v`
`Error: Could not find or load main class set`